# Run AJAX inside a popup function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run an ajax inside a popup function.

Basically, I have a very simple JavaScript function and I need to run an ajax call inside it.

To explain this, this is my simple popup function:

```
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {

}
window.close(); // Closing the popup
```

And this how I run my ajax inside it:

```
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    var  img = $('#img').val();

    alert(img);
    $.ajax({
        url:"folder/page.php",
        data:{img:img},
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success:function(result)
        {

        }
    });
}
window.close(); // Closing the popup
```

And this is how I call it:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('folder/page.php', 'Popup', 'width=640,height=480');">Some Text/a>
```

When I run my code, the popup opens properly but no ajax is being executed at all.

I've got this inside my `page.php` to make sure the ajax being sent/posted:

```
$img = $_POST['img'];

$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,$img);
fclose($file);
```

But nothing's being inserted into the `test.txt` file and it's always empty.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

EDIT:

This is my hidden input field (#img):

```
<input type="hidden" id="img" value="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
```

Comment: Have you tried adding window.close(); inside the success function of your ajax call?

Comment: Maybe you could try to open your dev tools (F12 in most of the browsers) in your browser and see if any message happens.
If not, try to add some console.log() in your JS file to see where your script stop.
If you have any message post it and maybe we could help you.

Comment: @PeterDarmis, great suggestion and that made it work in a way.. But, I stil' don't get the img:img inside the page.php. I get some random numbers for some strange reason!

Comment: you just write the img name in test.txt? Also be sure that window.close() is in the last line of your success function

Comment: @PeterDarmis, I'm trying to write the image name into the text file. yes... but instead of the image name, I get some random numbers!

Comment: What kind of element is #img. Is it on the parent or child window? If you are trying to get the html name attribute you should be using .attr("name");

Comment: try posting your form html code to check this @Kenji has a point there. Additionally you could add something like this also in your ajax call, beforeSend:function(){
console.log(img);
  }, also the contenttype is the default one in jquery ajax so you could delete that line if you wish.

Comment: @Kenji, #img is just a hidden input field. when I look into my log file, I get an `undifiend index img` in page.php! which means I'm not even getting the img input value posted at all!!!

Comment: @PeterDarmis, I'll try that now.

Comment: @Jackson i will post a complete answer i think i got the issue, is your hidden field in the opener (parent) window and not in the pop-up right?

Comment: you need to look in the context of the parent window. $("#img",window.opener.document)

Comment: @PeterDarmis, yes, the #img is inside the index file. the popup is the page.php and I need to get the value of #img using $_POST inside it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @PeterDarmis, I tried the beforeSend:function(){ console.log(img); }, as well and nothing inside my console whatsoever!

Comment: as @Kenji commented you need to look in the context of the parent window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add window.clode() inside your ajax success function.
Additionally i altered your ajax call a little assuming that you use a version later than 1.8

`Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`

```
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {


var img = window.opener.$("#img").val(); 

    var request = $.ajax({
        url:"folder/page.php",
        data:{img:img},
        type:"POST",
        beforeSend:function(){ console.log(img); }
});
request.done(function( result ) {
 // your result manipulation function
 ....
 window.close(); // close pop-up
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus ); 
window.close(); // close pop-up
});

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either! No errors and no img value in console at all.

Comment: I've added the hidden input field and its content to my question.

Comment: Just noticed something in your code. you are using the variable img but I don't see you creating that variable anywhere in your code!!

Comment: thanks but even that doesn't do anything. i'm literally pulling my hair out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111078/discussion-between-peter-darmis-and-jackson).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    var  img = $('#img').val();

    alert(img);
    $.ajax({
        url:"folder/page.php",
        data:$.param({img:img}),
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success:function(result)
        {
            window.close(); // Closing the popup
        }
    });
}
```

use $.param to pass your data.

Comment: No, i'm using `var img = window.opener.$("#img").val(); ` and `var img = $("#img").val();` which then I can simply use inside the PHP page as a post from the AJAX.

Comment: That's fine. But $img = $_POST['img']; in your code behind won't work until you have name attribute.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood.

Comment: you are wrong. I'm using AJAX to run my php and when you are using AJAX to run your php, you don't need name attribute. you can use the input's ID or even class name to create a variable.

Comment: I have updated my answer. to use $.param to pass data